# Does the soul have a physical body in the hereafter? (Sunni view)

Tags: sunni, jannah, soul, human-body

Will the people of paradise/heaven be physical beings or spiritual beings?

Here on Earth, I understand that we are physical beings with souls.

My question is, will the people of paradise/heaven also be physical beings with souls, or will they be souls without physical bodies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly by several evidence and sources of the Qur'an and the Hadith, that in hereafter soul will re-link with the body, both in terms of reward (in Paradise) or punishment (in the hellfire) ...

> وَضَرَبَ لَنَا مَثَلًا وَنَسِيَ خَلْقَهُ ۖ قَالَ مَن يُحْيِي الْعِظَامَ
>   وَهِيَ رَمِيمٌ
>
> And applies comparisons to Us, having forgotten his origin, and says:
>   "Who can put life into decayed bones?" [36:78]

.

> وَهُوَ الَّذِي يَبْدَأُ الْخَلْقَ ثُمَّ يُعِيدُهُ وَهُوَ أَهْوَنُ
>   عَلَيْهِ ۚ وَلَهُ الْمَثَلُ الْأَعْلَىٰ فِي السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْضِ
>   ۚ وَهُوَ الْعَزِيزُ الْحَكِيمُ
>
> It is He who first creates and then reverts it. This is how His law
>   works inevitably. His semblance is of the most sublime in the heavens
>   and the earth. He is all-mighty and all-wise. [30:27]

And this is evidence in the torment of the body in the fire ...

> إِنَّ الَّذِينَ كَفَرُوا بِآيَاتِنَا سَوْفَ نُصْلِيهِمْ نَارًا
>   كُلَّمَا نَضِجَتْ جُلُودُهُم بَدَّلْنَاهُمْ جُلُودًا غَيْرَهَا
>   لِيَذُوقُوا الْعَذَابَ ۗ إِنَّ اللَّـهَ كَانَ عَزِيزًا حَكِيمًا
>
> Indeed, those who disbelieve in Our verses - We will drive them into a
>   Fire. Every time their skins are roasted through We will replace them
>   with other skins so they may taste the punishment. Indeed, Allah is
>   ever Exalted in Might and Wise.[4:56]

And in this Hadith ...

> عَنِ الْحَسَنِ، قَالَ‏:‏ أَتَتْ عَجُوزٌ إِلَى النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه
>   وسلم، فَقَالَتْ‏:‏ يَا رَسُولَ اللهِ، ادْعُ اللَّهَ أَنْ يُدْخِلَنِي
>   الْجَنَّةَ، فَقَالَ‏:‏ يَا أُمَّ فُلانٍ، إِنَّ الْجَنَّةَ لا
>   تَدْخُلُهَا عَجُوزٌ، قَالَ‏:‏ فَوَلَّتْ تَبْكِي، فَقَالَ‏:‏
>   أَخْبِرُوهَا أَنَّهَا لا تَدْخُلُهَا وَهِيَ عَجُوزٌ إِنَّ اللَّهَ
>   تَعَالَى، يَقُولُ‏:‏ إِنَّا أَنْشَأْنَاهُنَّ إِنْشَاءً،
>   فَجَعَلْنَاهُنَّ أَبْكَارًا، عُرُبًا أَتْرَابًا‏.‏ ...
>
> Hasan Basri radiyallahu anhu says that an old woman came to
>   Rasoolullah sallallahu alaihe wasallam and made a request, O Messenger
>   of Allah make Dua that Allah grants me entrance into Jannah.
>
> Rasoolullah sallallahu alaihe wasallam replied, O Mother, an old woman
>   cannot enter Jannah. That woman started crying and began to leave.
>   Rasoolullah sallallahu alaihe wasallam said, Say to the woman that one
>   will not enter in a state of old age, but Allah will make all the
>   women of Jannah young virgins. Allah Ta'ala says, Lo! We have created
>   them a (new) creation and made them virgins, lovers, equal in age.
>   (Surah Waaqi'ah, 35-37).

This evidence and many others show that the body be re-created in the the Hereafter ...

Comment: I would like to add, "Those who reject our signs, We shall soon cast into the fire. As often as their skins are roasted through, We shall change them for fresh skins, that they may taste the chastisement. Truly Allah is Exalted in Power, Wise. (Qur'an 4:56)." Cos skin is very physical, isn't it? ;)